# retrieve the object_id of the Azure service principal

Tags: python, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-keyvault

How can I retrieve the object_id of an Azure service principal programatically using the Python APIs?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***I attempted to do the same in my environment and got the following results:***

To retrieve the **`ObjectID` of the Azure AD Application** try the below code:

[image]

```py
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from azure.graphrbac import GraphRbacManagementClient
from msgraph.core import GraphClient

def get_object_id():
    app_id = "AppID"
    tenant_id = "TenantID"
    client_id = "ClientID"
    client_secret = "ClientSecret"
    credential = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id, client_id, client_secret)        
    client = GraphClient(credential=credential)
    endpoint = "/applications"
    select = "displayName,id,appId"
    req_filter = f"appId eq '{app_id}'"
    request_url = f'{endpoint}?$select={select}&$filter={req_filter}'

    response = client.get(request_url)
    print(response.json()['value'][0]['id'])
get_object_id()
```

[image]

To get the **`ObjectID` of the Azure Service Principal (*Enterprise Application*)** try the below code:

```py
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from azure.graphrbac import GraphRbacManagementClient
from msgraph.core import GraphClient

def get_object_id():
    app_id = "AppID"
    tenant_id = "TenantID"
    client_id = "ClientID"
    client_secret = "ClientSecret"
    credential = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id, client_id, client_secret)        
    client = GraphClient(credential=credential)
    endpoint = "/servicePrincipals"
    select = "displayName,id,appId"
    req_filter = f"appId eq '{app_id}'"
    request_url = f'{endpoint}?$select={select}&$filter={req_filter}'

    response = client.get(request_url)
    print(response.json()['value'][0]['id'])
get_object_id()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I made a few minor changes, changed the assignments of `tenant_id`, `client_id`, `client_secret` to `os.environ.get` and the code returns the correct result. But still,  I needed to look up  the `app_id` in the portal. Do you know how I can fetch this with Python as well?

Comment: To fetch `ApplicationId`object Id of the application must be needed

Comment: AFAIK Some value of the application is needed to fetch details of the app.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It works!
Two comments:
1. The GraphRbacManagementClient object isn't used anywhere in the code - can be removed. 
2. Both the packages (azure-graphrbac and msgraph-core) aren't under development. The last contribution to msgraph-core was in 2021. Not sure how long they'll be supported.